# Ajax form in .done function need to do another ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, image-uploading

I have a form inside an **ajax done function** (Please note that it is inside the .done function)

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "?select_main",
  data: {},
})
.done(function(data) {

 <div>\n\
 <form id="frm_img" name="frm_img" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="?upload_sub"">\n\
 Select image to upload <br/>\n\
 <input type="file" name="inputimage" id="inputimage" style="border: 1px solid black; width: 300px;"/>\n\
 <input type="hidden"  id="id" name="id" class="form-control input-small" value="' + aData[0] + '" />\n\
 <br/><input type="button" id="btnupload" name="upload" value="Upload"/><form>\n\
 <div id="imagediv"></div>\n\
 </div>'
}};
```

On submitting the form, I need to do another ajax

```
       $(document).ready(function() {
                        $("#btnupload").on("click", function(e) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                        });



                        $("#btnupload").on("click", function() {
                            if (isBeingSent == true)
                                return false;

                            isBeingSent = true;


                            $.post(
                                    "?upload_sub", 
                                    {form: $("#frm_img").ajaxForm} 

                            );

                            $("#imagediv").html('');
                            $("#imagediv").html('<img src="loading.gif" id="loading" />"');
                            $("#frm_img").ajaxForm({
                                target: '#imagediv'
                            }).submit();
                            return false;

                        });


                    });
```

The Page does not refresh now, but how do i send the ajaxForm so that i can get it in my php?

My ?upload_sub is as follows:

```
 $allowedFiles = array('png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif');

    $arrfile = explode(".", $_FILES["inputimage"]["name"]);

    $index = count($arrfile) - 1;

    $extension = $arrfile[$index];

    if ((($_FILES["inputimage"]["type"] == "image/jpg") or
            ($_FILES["inputimage"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") or
            ($_FILES["inputimage"]["type"] == "image/png") or
            ($_FILES["inputimage"]["type"] == "image/gif")) and
            in_array($extension, $allowedFiles)) {
        $filename = $_FILES["inputimage"]["name"];
        $tmpfile = $_FILES["inputimage"]["name"];
        $filesize = $_FILES["inputimage"]["size"];
        $temp = $_FILES["inputimage"]["tmp_name"];


        if ($filesize <= 1048576) {


            move_uploaded_file($temp, $pathimg . $filename);
            //           echo '<img src="' . $pathimg . $filename . '" id="prof_pic"/>';
        } else {
            echo 'File size exceeded.';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Invalid file.';
    }
```

Is the below code ok?

```
      $.post(
                                    "?upload_sub", 
                                    {form: $("#frm_img").ajaxForm} 

                            );
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first thing which i suggest is to make the button type="button" intead of type =" submit" if the button will always be used to do ajax call.

```
<input type="button" id="btnupload" name="upload" value="Upload"/>
```

Second probelm which i noticed is in

```
$("btnupload").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

it seems you forget to add # before the id, Try

```
$("#btnupload").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: @stackAshAshna :  if the header problem is solved then please mark it as answer for others to save their time, i am looking into your next issue

Comment: @stackAshAshna :  instead of $.post, what i suggest you is to use $.ajax because of the multiple parameters you can specify there. check the added answer if it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
Use Input Tag Properly in HTML:

    <input type="button" id="btnupload" name="upload" value="Upload"/>

On the btnupload button Onclick Call UploadImage Function:

function UploadImage() {
            var imgFile = document.getElementById('myFile');
            if (imgFile.files.length > 0) {
                var BusinessPartnerName = $('#TxtBusinessPartnerName').val();
                BusinessPartnerName = TrimString(BusinessPartnerName);
               var ext = "." + imgFile.files[0].name.substr(imgFile.files[0].name.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
                var imagename = BusinessPartnerName + ext;
                var imagesize = imgFile.files[0].size;
                var RootFolder = "Media,";
                var SubDomain = userInfo.TenantId + ",";
                var SubFolder = userInfo.CompanyId + ",";
                var BaseFolder = "BusinessPartner";
                var imagePath = RootFolder + SubDomain + SubFolder + BaseFolder;
                var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                var imageUrl = userInfo.ImageUri + '/Upload?imagePath=' + imagePath + '&imageName=' + imagename + '&imageSize=' + imagesize;
                request.open('POST', imageUrl);
                request.send(imgFile.files[0]);
                request.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (request.readyState == 4) {
                        if (request.status == 200) {
                            imageFileUri = request.responseText;
                            ///Call another Ajax Service Here ....
                            }

                        } else {
                           Show Exception Error Message Here
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
            else {
                Show Exception Error Message Here
            }
        }
```

Comment: I am using php for the upload. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To send the data , use

```
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "?select_main",
      data: $("#frm_img").serailize(),
success:function(){}
    })
```

you can also Use the below to serialize

```
 jQuery('#frm_img').serializeArray()
```

if you want to use the post method the there is a sample

```
   $.post(url, $("#frm_img").serialize());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function editRow(oTable, nRow) {

        var img = $("#Image_Path").val();
        var optionMain;
        var MainItem;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "?select_main",
            data: {},
        })

                .done(function(data) {
                    var aData = oTable.fnGetData(nRow);
                    var jqTds = $('>td', nRow);


                    jqTds[0].innerHTML = '<input type="hidden" id="Item_Details_Id" class="form-control input-small" value="' + aData[0] + '">';
                    jqTds[1].innerHTML = '<select id="Item_Main" class="form-control input-small"></select>';
                    jqTds[2].innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="Item_Name" class="form-control input-small" value="' + aData[2] + '">';
                    jqTds[3].innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="Price" class="form-control input-small" value="' + aData[3] + '">';   //       jqTds[3].innerHTML = '<input type="file" name="Image_Path"  id="Image_Path"  />';

                    jqTds[4].innerHTML = '<div>\n\
<form id="frm_img" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="?upload_sub">\n\
Select image to upload <br/>\n\
<input type="file" name="inputimage" id="inputimage" style="border: 1px solid black; width: 300px;"/>\n\
<input type="hidden"  id="id" name="id" class="form-control input-small" value="' + aData[0] + '" />\n\
<br/><input type="submit" id="btnupload" name="upload" value="Upload" /><form>\n\
<div id="imagediv"></div>\n\
</div>'
                    jqTds[5].innerHTML = '<a class="edit" href="">Save</a>';
                    jqTds[6].innerHTML = '<a class="cancel" href="">Cancel</a>';
                    jqTds[0].style.display = "none";


                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        $('#btnupload').click(function() {
                            $("#imagediv").html('');
                            $("#imagediv").html('<img src="loading.gif" id="loading" />"');
                            $("#frm_img").ajaxForm({
                                target: '#imagediv'
                            }).submit();
                            return false;
                        });
                    });


                    optionMain = $.parseJSON(data);

                    for (i = 0; i < optionMain.length; i++) {
                        MainItem = optionMain[i];

                        $('#Item_Main').append(MainItem);

                    }

                });

    }
```

This code work well.
Thanks Shiv for your help :)